# How do I insert a localStorage variable into ng-repeat so the user can change the filter

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

Right now I have a couple of buttons that will insert a value into localStorage. I thought I could get the value and insert it into the ng-repeat line to change the filtering.

If I use plain filtering, this works:

```
<div class='segment' ng-repeat="x in names | filter:x.bodyType='Buggy'">
```

But this does not work:

```
<div class='segment' ng-repeat="x in names | filter:x.bodyType='<script>var show = localStorage.getItem('show'); show</script>'">
```

I'm not using Jquery or any other JS or CSS framework except AngularJS. Not using PHP. This is simple HTML5 for a web app.

Comment: Update:  If interested, I made a working web app example here: https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/displaying-a-database-javascript-array-with-angularjs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the object dynamically and pass it to filter.

```js
$scope.show = 'A';
$scope.base = function() {
    return $scope.show;
};
$scope.bodyType = function() {
    return {bodyType: $scope.base()};
};
$scope.objs = [{bodyType: 'A'}, {bodyType: 'B'}];
```

```html
<button ng-click="show='B'">Button</button>
<div ng-repeat="x in objs | filter: bodyType()">{{x}}</div>
```

Comment: So happy with this!! How would you code this to include a separate button to show all the database content (no filtering)?

Comment: I figured out how to show the entire DB on page load:  $scope.show = '';

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Angular is capable of interpolating the expression `<script>...</script>`. I suggest you have a function in your controller that gets the value using localStorage service like:

```js
$scope.bodyType = function() {
  localStorage.getItem('show');
};
```

```html
<div class='segment' ng-repeat="x in names | filter:x.bodyType='{{bodyType()}}'">
```

Comment: I thought the ng-click directive on the buttons would apply, but I can't make that work either:  http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp . Tried: <button ng-click="show=Buggy" ... Then: <div class='segment' data-ng-repeat="x in names | filter:x.bodyType={{ show }}"> Not working.

Comment: it should be `show='Buggy'` and `'{{show}}'`. From the documentation, i think my earlier answer is not correct. We should either pass string/function/object. I don't think the expression involving functions like i wrote `filter:x.bodyType='{{bodyType()}}'` will work. I suggest a build an object and use it to filter - check the following answer.